# These animals can be dangerous

Tags: modal-verbs

What does "can" mean in this sentence?

> These animals can be dangerous.

Some people say it indicates possibility, i.e., "I don't know if these animals are dangerous. They are possibly/probably dangerous".

Other people say it indicates what is true sometimes or in some circumstances, i.e., "these animals are dangerous sometimes or in some circumstances".

Which opinion is correct? I'm totally confused.

Answer (score 1):

If it were a matter of speculating as to likelihood, I would be more  apt to say, "These animals might be dangerous." Here the idea is that I don't know that they are dangerous, but that I don't think we should be careless, either.

If, on the other hand, I were contemplating circumstances that might lead these animals to be dangerous, then I would be more  apt to say, "These animals can be dangerous," possibly as a warning that we ought to be cautious around them and not do  anything careless or reckless.

Comment: This doesn't  really answer the question. I would say that the sentence means 'Being around these animals is quite likely to put you in danger'.

Answer (score 0):

Context would help,  but here I'd interpret the meaning to be the second.

The speaker is certain that the animals are sometimes dangerous, but is uncertain if they are dangerous right now.

As I said, context would help:

> Elephants can be dangerous, especially the adult males when they are in "must". But they can also be very gentle, especially towards their handlers who have built up a relationship.